# jQuery add class to parent if child has specific class

Tags: html, jquery

I'm hoping to get some assistance with a little jQuery script.
I've been going through all the posts I can find here on stackoverflow and been trying to piece things together to achieve this result.

The result I'm after is this -
If a class .fes-el also has the class .fn_tags_field

Add the class .updated_parent to the parent class.

I'm not really experienced with programming in any sort of way. So I'm probably messing up something really basic.
Any help would be appreciated.

This is what I've been able to piece together so far.
The reason I want to use .parent() is because there are multiple elements with the class .fes-el.
My previous attempts without usiing .parent() resulted in all parent classes getting .updated_parent added.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
   if ($(".fes-el").hasClass('fn_tags_field')) {
      $(this).parent().addClass('updated_parent');
   }
});
```

This is how the html is made up.

```
<div class="fes-field fn_container_start">
   <div class="fes-el fn_tags_field download_tag">      
      <div class="fes-label"></div>
      <div class="fes-fields"></div>
   </div>
</div>
```

My hopes were that using that bit of jQuery would add the class .updated_parent after fn_container_start

I appreciate all the help I can get.

Regards,
Morten

Comment: The code will only be executed at runtime: meaning that if at some point later in time the class is added to the element, that will not work. Is that the issue you are facing?

Comment: following up on Terry. The code will only run once when the page has loaded. So if you want to run the code after an event has occurred on your page you will need to add your code into a function. Then call the function at the appropriate time. Something like - $('selector').click(yourFunction);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function JSFunc(){
    $(".fes-el.fn_tags_field").each(function (index, value) { 
        $(value).parent().addClass("updated_parent");
     })
    
      
}
```

This will loop through all of the divs find the divs that match all the required classes and add your updated class to the parent.

This is not an optimized solution since you havent said when this would need to happen, all that you have to do is execute this code whenever you need to update the classes

Comment: Perfect, I can see I was way off.
I was hoping for it to execute on page load. Will this work for that?

Comment: Depends on how your changing the classes if your doing it manually then yes you can run this at launch but if your updating the classes at runtime then run this code after and itll do it for you.

Comment: The classes stay static, nothing changes on the page while the user is doing stuff.
When I try to add the code, it still doesn't add anything to the parent class.

Comment: if the classes are static why not add the classes to the html file rather than at runtime.

Comment: Ah right, because I have no control over the html. But I have the ability to add jquery like this to append elements.

Comment: I have changed the code to the correct version, i have tested this aswell and it seems to work fine, if this answer is correct then please mark it as such.

Comment: Thank you that worked! Maybe it's wordpress thing, but I had to do this to make it work correctly for me

jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
 $(".fes-el.fn_tags_field").each(function (index, value) { 
     $(value).parent().addClass("updated_parent");
     })
});